# Prevent options popup closing without user sets an option

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have `options.html` and `options.js`, where user should set required option for an extension works properly, and click on `save`. Setted option is saved in storage and gotten later by `background.js`.

Further i have `welcome.html`, which loads immediately after successful installation. It has an `iframe` with `options.html`.

How can i prevent closing `welcome.html` without user sets any option?

Comment: @wOxxOm Tried to add `window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "test"
  };` to `options.js`, but still can close both of `options.html` and `welcome.html` without any alert and no error in console... Can you describe more detailedly what where?

Comment: i'm completely lost. Do you mean, it won't work with an url like `chrome://extensions/`? What would be then the way to prevent closing `welcome.html` without selected option?

Comment: Slowly please:) Direct include of javascript into HTML is no longer allowed, correct? If i want to add javascript to options.html - i add it to options.js. If i want to add javascript to welcome.html - where should i insert it?

Comment: Nearly got it! Added to `options.js` this one `window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit(){
    alert("test");
    return false;
}` - but it works only if DevTools are open. Otherwise the alert is blocked and i see just a line in the console `alert blocked`. How can i get it displayed (no longer blocked)?

Comment: I thought you relate to your solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33011168/1992004. But i can't yet make it working with my `window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit(){
    var e=document.getElementById("wptk").value;//alert(e);
    if(e===""){
        alert("nothing selected");
        return false;
    }
}`

Comment: hm, ok, we are clear with it - i didn't understand, what you was meaning:) Maybe you can explain, what did you indeed mean?

Comment: Which suggested code? From you first comment in this topic? Yes, sure, tried it, after adding `welcome.js` to manifest as content script. But nothing happened (nothing what i've realized): no console messages, everything can be closed without selecting an option. But i'm pretty sure, just the varbatim adding will not do the trick...

Comment: Did it exactly as you said, with no visible result. But i think it is just silly what i did: added plain two lines one after one `window.onbeforeunload = () => '';
window.onbeforeunload = null;`

Comment: Did it - but single line `window.onbeforeunload = () => '';` makes no visible result too.

Comment: that would be nice - i can get no reasonable example for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.onbeforeunload.

welcome.html:

```
<script src="welcome.js"></script>
<iframe src="options.html"></iframe>
```

welcome.js:

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => '';
```

Comment: If i install extension and open DevTools - it works, i get an alert on closing of `welcome.html`. I can immediately close DevTools - i will still get an alert. But if i install an extension and don't open DevTools - i can close `welcome.html` without an alert.

Comment: Modern browsers will only block unload if you interacted with the page, for example clicked something. There's no way around this.

Comment: Even scroll is not the kind of interaction, which triggers blocking ability. But I'm trying to make a workaround exactly for this case, where user closes a page without do something... Do you maybe have an idea - what is the best way to notify user under these circumstances about he forgot to do something?

Comment: You can show an `alert('foo')` first. Or use chrome.tab.onRemoved in the background script and just reopen the tab util it's saved. Both methods are terrible UX-wise though. There are no alternatives AFAIK.

Comment: `terrible UX-wise` - agreed. Will your solution work you published here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33011168/1992004 ?

Comment: No, that's a different case.